# Replace color for all layers

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, export, color-conversion, imagemagick

I have a file with about 500 layers, and I need to replace a color in all of them. I looked through different solutions here and elsewhere, and they all suggested using an adjustment layer or something similar. This doesn't help much - the layers are used for animation so it would break everything.

The best I could come up with is export layers to files, run a batch on those files, and load them back in. However, 15 minutes later it only managed me to export 3 frames out of 500. Is this some kind of a joke? The whole `gif` is 300kb and imagemagick managed to export it in a fraction of a second, though I'm not happy with what it did to transparency.

## **Update:**

`ffmpeg` did the exporting just fine, now I'm trying to get photoshop to replace color. I select a gray color `#e1e1e1`, click on the result, and type in the required color `#f2f6f8`. It suggests `hue -160, sat +30, lightness +8`, which does pretty much nothing at all. How is it possible that when I specify the result color I need, it fails to figure out how to do the replacement?

I ended up using a short piece of code to do the color conversion (because I had a `png` library at hand) and imagemagick to convert it back to `gif`. So much for the almighty photoshop, failed me at all 3 steps.

Comment: I don't get why an adjustment layer messes with the animation. Could you explain that?

Comment: I guess I was wrong there, I thought it would add a new frame instead of affecting all existing frames. I just don't understand why its not possible to select all frames and click image->replace color. Still, the process of importing/exporting lots of images into photoshop takes so long that I decided to stick with imagemagick.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

First choose the color you want to change with **Eyedroper**.

Hide all layers. Right click the icon eye in any layer and choose: **Show hide all other layers**, repeat it untill you hide all Layers.

Select the first layer and create a new action. Name it as your wish.

While the action is recording, right click the eye icon of the selected layer and choose **Show this layer**.

Go to: **Select>>Color range>>Sampled colors** and click the color sampled in the toolbar.

Go to: **Image>>Adjustments>>Hue saturation**. Find the new color you want.

Now hide the layer. This will let you know the action has finished.

Stop the action.

Select the next layer and play the action...

Now the action will show the selected layer, select the old color, replace with the new color, hide the selected layer and stop.

Good Luck.

Answer (score -3):

In Photoshop you can select all layers and make a group from them, then set a "Color Overlay" layer style on the group via "blending options".